# Google Scripts - Google Forms - Get Strings of Items

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am having some difficulty capturing the names of the items within my Google Form. I want to be able to store the form item names to then be used with if/else statements to better filter my responses. I am able to get the number of items within my form, but cannot pull the names of those form items. Can anyone help me figure out what method I'm missing?

```
  //Capture Questions 
  var items = form.getItems();

  //Capture Question Titles, Provides # of items in "[items, items, ...]" format
  var itemsTitle = items.toString();

//Does nothing
var titles = itemsTitle.getTitle();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.getTitle()` has to be called on an [item object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item), not a string:

```
for ( var i in items ) {
  var title = items[i].getTitle()
}
```

or `items[0].getTitle()` if you know the exact index of the item

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was exactly what I was looking for.